# Как удалить записи если больше 20

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Дело в том что, мне нужно удалить если записей больше 20ти и при этом только старых, то есть по дате.
Где-то нашел SQL запрос

```
DELETE tt
FROM 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT uid             --- these 3 lines can be replaced
    FROM tableX                     --- with:   UserTable AS du
  ) AS du                           --- a table that you probably have
JOIN
  tableX AS tt
ON  tt.uid = du.uid
AND tt.timestampColumn >
    ( SELECT timestampColumn AS ts
      FROM tableX
      WHERE uid = du.uid 
      ORDER BY ts ASC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 199
    )
```

но это совсем непонятно. Могу удалить если больше 20ти, но проблема в том что 2 проверки, а я в SQLite новичок, каша в голове.

У меня есть такие столбцы:

```
private static final String TABLE_SEARCH = "search_table";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
```

Как в моем случае использовать запрос выше. И как переделать db.delete()?

Comment: какие именно надо удалить? по какому полю? По KEY_DATE самые старые?

Comment: если количество записей больше 20 то удалить по дате..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM search_table
WHERE date NOT IN (
    SELECT date 
    FROM search_table 
    ORDER BY date desc 
    LIMIT 20
)
```

Писал на коленке, возможны опечатки, но идея такая.
Внутренним запросом выбираем все, что нужно оставить, то есть топ 20 записей по дате, а внешним - удаляем все, кроме того, что выбрал внутренний.

Вот еще вариант, этот получше:

```
DELETE FROM search_table
WHERE id < SELECT id from (
    SELECT id, date 
    FROM search_table 
    ORDER BY date desc 
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 19
)
```

Comment: Да, тут может быть проблема, если даты полностью совпадут

Comment: Использовать так? String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM search_table WHERE id < SELECT id from (SELECT id, date FROM search_table ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 19 )"; db.execSQL(deleteQuery)

Comment: @Omuradil, ну попробуйте и так, и не так

Comment: А как перевести на обычный db.delete?

Comment: @Omuradil, это сложный запрос. Насколько я знаю, его нельзя выполнить в delete